# difference between not to verb , to not + verb

Tags: word-order, infinitives

> "Name three things that, if you were told were part of the job, would cause you ***to not*** take the position. "

I've just come across this sentence while reading the news.

Question is: Why ***to not*** is used instead of ***not to***? This usage in this way imposes different meaning?

Comment: You can use a > to put something in a text area.

Comment: @Catija thank you.Another question again just occured to my mind.Why did you put "while". I've just come across this sentence ,reading the news.Can't it be understood what I mean to say? Reading the news,I've just come across this sentence.So what would you say for the place and meaning of "reading the news"?

Comment: You're welcome.  As to your other question, It's more natural. A native speaker would not use that phrasing on a regular basis... if you used other words: *I came across this dog, window shopping.* it sounds like the **dog** is the one doing the shopping! English can be pretty understandable even when grammar is incorrect, so "being understood" is not a very good standard for proper English use.

Comment: @CihangirÇam Placing a ***not*** in the *to-infinitive* clause will make the whole non-finite clause negative. You have a choice while placing ***not*** in that non-finite clause. Either you can place it before *to* or between *to* and the infinitive form of verb. But placing the ***not*** before **to** is more common. The meaning won't depend on where the ***not*** is placed.

Answer (score 4):

.....would cause you to not take the position.

In the sentence, the infinitive "to take" has been split. Instead of  using 
"not to take",  "to not take"  has been used.
In fact, both the phrases convey the same meaning. The only difference is that the former phrase is more common and clear than the latter phrase. It's up to you to use a phrase that is much preferable and clear or the phrase that isn't common and easy on the ear.