# Using not to <verb> or to not <verb>

Tags: verbs, word-order, infinitives

Which of these is the correct one, or are both correct?

1. I moved slowly, to not wake my parents. - Intended meaning
2. I moved slowly, not to wake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between not to verb , to not + verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52958/difference-between-not-to-verb-to-not-verb) Also [“to not” vs “not to”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112893/to-not-vs-not-to)

Answer (score -1):

Actually both are usable but the mostly used fluent way of doing it will be "**not to < verb >**"

> I moved slowly, not to wake my parents.

Because what you are ***not*** trying ***to do*** is waking your parents.

Comment: I don't see why *what you are **not** trying **to do** is waking your parents* is any more "explanatory" than *what you are trying **to do** is **not** wake your parents*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can easily relate the amount of usage! Also I did not imply it is explanatory I did imply it is mostly used and more fluent.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive

Comment: The "fluent" versions of that text are *I moved slowly, **so as [not to / to not]** wake my parents*. Usually [***so as not to***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so+as+not+to%2Cso+as+to+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20as%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20as%20to%20not%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cso%20as%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20as%20to%20not%3B%2Cc0), but there's nothing wrong with the sequence ***so as to not*** there - it's just much less common.

Comment: At least *part* of my downvote is because ***what you are not trying to do is waking your parents*** is seriously non-idiomatic. Native speakers would almost always use the infinitive form ***is [to] wake your parents*** (where including ***to*** is effectively a stylistic choice).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98906/discussion-between-berker-yuceer-and-fumblefingers).